# How to remove KVO methods from Xcode auto-completion popup?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

When I write a class in Objective-C Xcode is keep showing automatically inferred KVO methods. Well, I don't use KVO in my code, and I will. Then it's simply bordering me, and actually number of the methods are more than the methods declared in my class.

How to remove those KVO methods from auto-completion window? I believe there's a mechanism to control this, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I extracted out the properties which causes KVO method generation to a separated protocol, and it doesn't border me anymore. This is the best workaround for me now.